# how to connect service to django admin panel actions

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have the model `Machine`, that is inherited from `models.Model`:

```
class Machine(models.Model):
...
```

The model is registered in django admin panel using:

```
admin.site.register(Machine)
```

When I create new model using `Add...` button, I need to proceed some service code, along with creating new Machine.

How can I connect my service code to default django admin panel?

I've tried to connect code using re-defining methods in model class, based on information I found in Internet, but that didn't work.

Comment: Check these topics helps you https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/models/#model-methods
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/signals/